# Hyperlink not added to image in using xlsxwriter for c++ on RHEL 5.9

Tags: xlsxwriter, libxlsxwriter

I have inserted image in .xlsx file thru c on RHEL 5.9 using xlsxwriter but cannot add hyperlink to it using url attribute. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I going to guess that you are talking about the C [libxlsxwriter](https://libxlsxwriter.github.io/) and not the Python [XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html).

In which case the C library doesn't currently support urls for images. The Python module [does](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-insert-image).

**Update**:

As of version 0.8.9 libxlsxwriter supports [images with urls](https://libxlsxwriter.github.io/worksheet_8h.html#a0b05e75e2c2a5c3452374714cdb2b79b).

Comment: Thank you Sir for prompt reply.

Comment: But can you suggest any way out? The client is insisting and I have no option.

Comment: You can either use the Python module or open a feature request against libxlsxwriter. However it is likely to be a few months before it is added.

Comment: Sir, is it possible to embed the python script for writing xlsx file  in original c program?